# User table Type Error. dataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have userDetails page with a Header, I am displaying user list on this page using jQuery. It load fine initially when the complete page load but when I reload another page using ajax on same page div and return back on userList, List does not load user data and just display header with following error in console.

```
VM89:4 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(…)
```

If I again click on same userList menu now it will display table data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#usertable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
            var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();

            var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"; 

            var postURL = contextPath + "/GetUserDetails";

            $.post(postURL, {userId: value}, function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                var url = contextPath + "/jsp/userDetails.jsp";
                $("#contentDiv").load(url, obj, function() {});
            });
        });
    });
```

Included follwing JS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is likely related to having multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: Can you check imported jQuery and do let me know which one I should remove?

Answer (score -1):

You should have all dataTable link in that particular page only where you are using the dataTable or you can create common page where all the links are loaded and this common file should included into the dataTable List page.